# Using TouchXML how can I count tags that starts with specific texts

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, touchxml

Suppose I have an **XML** file that has tags Reg0, Reg1, Reg2. . . The "Reg" prefix is fixed.

How can I count the number of tags that starts with Reg text using **TouchXML**?

I can search for Reg text in my whole document, but may be this is not the right procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the if check the current element in the xml document using `hasPrefix` or using `rangeOfString`. I would recommend you to use `NSXMLParser` which is built in iOS. Using  `NSXMLParser` you could check the `elementName` when parsing the XML document, you could check for the string what you are looking for

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName hasPrefix:@"Reg"])
        regCount++;
}
```

or you can use `rangeOfString` also for `elementName`

```
if ([elementName rangeOfString:@"Reg"].location!=NSNotFound)
        regCount++;
```

Comment: I used NSXMLParser in all of my previous projects. But that projects was started by another developer, and it is impossible now to change the parser.

But the has prefix will help me. I think I can get a solution now.